# Do I need to add \0 to the end of a string literal being passed into a function?

Tags: c, string

I have this function:

```
void printError(char* pszOrigin, int nErr) {...}
```

When calling it with a literal string:

```
printError("LScreateModel",nErr);
```

Do I need to append a `\0` to the end of the string literal `"LScreateModel"`?
Or does it get one automatically?

Comment: It's automatic. A string literal always has a NUL terminator at the end. So, for example, the string literal `"abc"` is actually four characters (`'a' 'b' 'c' '\0'`), not three.

Comment: No, you do not - a string literal will already have a terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't. String literals are already null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

It is added automatically, since you're creating a const char * with the string literal.

> A string literal like "hello" is considered a constant C string, and typically has its data type specified as const char* (pointer to a char constant).

More information about C strings can be found [here](https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/strings.html).

Comment: It's added automatically regardless of whether you use `char *` or `const char *` (the later being the proper type, the former allowed for compatibility with older code)